# Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R$ then $I \subset R$ s.t. $I.M = M$ then there is $x \in I$ s.t. $(1+x)M = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am stuck with the proof of the nakyama lemma which states that:

$I.M = \{\sum a.m | a \in I , m \in M \} \subset M$(submodule)

Let $S = \{m_1, \cdots m_r \}$ be a generating set of $M$.

$m_i \in I.M$

$m_1 = a_{11}.m_1 + \cdots a_{r1}m_r $

$\vdots$

$m_r = a_{r1}m_1 + \cdots a_{rr}m_r$

We can then generate a matrix $A$ with entries in $a_{ij}$ and a matrix $M$ ..

**Edit 1** Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $(R, m)$. If $mM = M$, then $M = 0$ where $R$ is a local ring.

This is the corollary to the above theorem and I took $x = 1+m'$ where $m' \in m$ then $(1+m')M = 0  \implies M + m'M = 0 \implies M + M = 0 \implies M = 0$

Comment: Define $B := A - I$. Let $\mathbf{m} = [m_1 \; \cdots \; m_r]^{\mathsf T}$. Then, you have $B\mathbf{m} = \mathbf{0}$.  
Multiply with an appropriate matrix to get $\det(B) I \mathbf{m} = \mathbf{0}$. Conclude that $\det(B)$ annihilates $M$. Conclude the result about $A$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I can conclude that det($B$) annihilates $M$ as $det(B)Im = 0$ and $m$ generates $M$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Can you complete it from there?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I am stuck from this point. My professor suggested me to use the fact that $det(B) = 1 + x$ where $x \in I$ . I am not sure why that would hold?

Comment: The proof of your corollary is not quite correct. For instance, you've never actually used local-ity of the ring.

Comment: Oh how do I rectify it ?

Comment: Use the fact that any element outside $\mathfrak{m}$ is a unit. In particular, given any $m \in \mathfrak{m}$, the element $1 + m$ is a unit. So you've gotten that a unit annihilates $M$, which means that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, defining $B := I - A$, we see that $\det(B)$ annihilates $M$.
Now, we wish to show that $\det(B) = 1 + x$ for some $x \in I$.
Note that $B$ looks like
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} + 1 & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1r} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} + 1 & \cdots & a_{2r} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{r1} & a_{r2} & \cdots & a_{rr} + 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
(Is it okay to use the signs like I've used above?)

The result can be proven by induction. For the inductive step: assume that $r \geqslant 2$ and that the determinant of lower-right $(r - 1) \times (r - 1)$ submatrix is of the form $1 + a$ for some $a \in I$. Then, expanding the determinant along the first row gives you
$$\det(B) = (a_{11} + 1)(1 + a) + \underbrace{a_{12} \cdot \text{something} + \cdots + a_{1r} \cdot \text{something}}_{\in I}.$$
The first term above can be written as
$$(a_{11} + 1)(1 + a) = 1 + \underbrace{a_{11} + a + a a_{11}}_{\in I}.$$
Thus, $\det(B) \in 1 + I$.

Comment: Well, technically the main diagonal of $B$ would look like $1-a_{kk}$ but you can just define $a_{kk}'=-a_{kk}$ to get your form (well, this requires the presence of a unit $1$ in our base ring $R$ but I'd take this as given).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani can you check my edit. please..

Comment: @mrtaurho: That's the reason I've left the note "(Is it okay to use the signs like I've used above?)" And yes, I'm assuming there's a unit in the ring because a $1$ is written in the question itself.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I assumed (maybe by mistake) that this was a part you were unsure about and answered accordingly.

Comment: @mrtaurho Ah okay, no I wasn't unsure but was leaving that for the reader to justify. In any case, any unsure reader will now know it because of your comment. :)